# почему не работает построитель запросов laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

```
    $ordersDay = $user->orders() 
     ->selectRaw('status, count() as count') 
     ->where('orders.created_at', '>', Carbon::today()) 
     ->groupByRaw('status') 
     ->get();
    
    //вот так работает но нужно получить orders которые привязаны к определенному user 
             $ordersDay = DB::table('orders')
                ->selectRaw('status, count(*) as count')
                ->where('orders.created_at', '>', Carbon::today())
                ->groupByRaw('status')
                ->get();

//Model User
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function orders(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, 
              Customer::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: *нужно получить orders которые привязаны к определенному user* Ну значит, надо добавить в код условие этой привязки.

Comment: как именно? просто в orders нет поля user_id там есть customer_id т.е а уже в customers  есть user_id **** У usera есть много customers а у customers уже много orders так вот я вытягиваю user - ом orders через связь ко многим через

Comment: Значит, надо правильно связать таблицы, и уже из связанного агломерата извлекать нужные данные. [Laravel - Query Builder - Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins)

Comment: Критическую дополнительную информацию следует добавлять в вопрос, а не только в комментарий.

Comment: Если вы хотите через `DB::table('orders')` сделать, то у вас не хватает условия `->where('orders.user_id', $user->id)`

Comment: @Knyaz71 у orders таблицы нет user_id там есть customer_id а уже у customers есть user_id

у users много customers а у customers много orders

так вот мне нужно вытащить orders определенного user

Comment: А чем не устраивает запрос через модели? Если через `DB` то придется сделать парочку `->leftJoin()`